# Android: ScrollView force to bottom

Tags: android, android-scrollview

I would like a ScrollView to start all the way at the bottom. Any methods?

Comment: I think its just scrollTo(), yea I just checked the dev docs for ScrollView. Easy peasy.

Answer (score 341, accepted):

`scroll.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN)` also should work.

Put this in a `scroll.Post(Runnable run)`

Kotlin Code

```
scrollView.post {
   scrollView.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN)
}
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to do anything, any suggestions?
I tried it on onCreate and later in the onClick of a button.

Comment: It doesn't seems to work on changing orientation. Otherwise its working.

Comment: This doesn't work if the layout size has changed right before calling it. It needs to be posted instead.

Comment: This and below, won't work until you give some time to the view to inflate fully, just simplifying ademar answer.  scrollView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                  scrollView.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_UP // Or Down);
            }
        }, 1000);

Comment: scroll.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN) will lead to the change of focus. That will bring some strange behavior when there are more than one focusable views, e.g two EditText.  Check another solution I provide at the bottom.

Comment: `scroll.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN)` will lead to the change of focus. That will bring some strange behavior when there are more than one focusable views, e.g two EditText. Check my answer below.

Comment: See answer below

Comment: In those case were scroll.scrollTo(0, sc.getBottom()) don't work, use scroll.post. Example:
scroll.post(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
  scroll.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
  }
});

Comment: @eCDroid: That was not in my original answer; it was added in an edit. Based on some of the other answers on the question, my guess is that the concern is whether the `ScrollView` is laid out at the time of the `fullScroll()` call. If so, a more efficient approach, if you are using Kotlin, is to use [`doOnLayout` from Android KTX](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/core/view/package-summary#doonlayout).

Comment: @EngineSense That was exactly my issue, i thought nothing worked, but the layout simply needed some milliseconds to adjust to new size! (I used 500 ms btw)

Comment: `binding.scroll.run { post { fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN) } }` 
easy;)

Answer (score 363):

you should run the code inside the scroll.post like this:

```
scroll.post(new Runnable() {            
    @Override
    public void run() {
           scroll.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN);              
    }
});
```

Comment: there's some way without lose focus current element, when i do this i lose the focus of my current element (different from scrollview)

Comment: This is needed only in cases where the layout has not yet been measured and layouted (for example if you run it in onCreate). In cases like pressing a button, .post() is not needed.

Comment: If you don't want to focus on the ScrollView, you can use `scroll.scrollTo(0, scroll.getHeight());` to jump to the bottom, or `scroll.smoothScrollTo(0, scroll.getHeight());` for a smoother scroll

Comment: Isn't this code a possible memory leak? An anonymous Runnable is created that holds a reference to an activity (scroll)view. If the activity gets destroyed while the runnable is executing its task, it will leak a reference to the scrollview, no?

Comment: In Kotlin: `scrollView.post { scrollView.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN) }`

Comment: @AlbertVilaCalvo, the code in your comment worked  for me and took my scroll to the very end. Most of the solutions here were stopping the scroll slightly before the end for me. Thanks !!

Answer (score 133):

`scroll.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN)` will lead to the change of focus. That will bring some strange behavior when there are more than one focusable views, e.g two EditText. There is another way for this question.

```
    View lastChild = scrollLayout.getChildAt(scrollLayout.getChildCount() - 1);
    int bottom = lastChild.getBottom() + scrollLayout.getPaddingBottom();
    int sy = scrollLayout.getScrollY();
    int sh = scrollLayout.getHeight();
    int delta = bottom - (sy + sh);

    scrollLayout.smoothScrollBy(0, delta);
```

This works well.

**Kotlin Extension**

```
fun ScrollView.scrollToBottom() {
    val lastChild = getChildAt(childCount - 1)
    val bottom = lastChild.bottom + paddingBottom
    val delta = bottom - (scrollY+ height)        
    smoothScrollBy(0, delta)
}
```

Or if you want to further enhance to check whether it is already at the bottom before scrolling, you can do something like this:

```
    fun ScrollView.scrollToBottom() {
    val lastChild = children.lastOrNull() ?: return
    val bottom = lastChild.bottom + paddingBottom
    val currentY = height + scrollY
    val alreadyAtBottom = bottom <= currentY
    if (!alreadyAtBottom) {
        val delta = bottom - currentY
        smoothScrollBy(0, delta)
    } else {
        // already at bottom, do nothing
    }
}
```

Comment: So glad I didn't have to waste any more time on this. Just what I needed

Comment: This should have more upvotes.  It is the best answer by far.

Comment: This is the best answer present here.

Comment: Tried everything else on this page, even the stuff way below this.  This was the only thing that worked, and it doesn't cause my EditText to lose focus.  Thank you.

Comment: If you need to scroll down while keyboard is showing up, combine this code with [this library](https://github.com/yshrsmz/KeyboardVisibilityEvent). Works like a charm.

Comment: less hacky solution without any doubt

Comment: This should be considered the right answer, works perfectly

Comment: ScrollView only has one child which is a ViewGroup so you can just say 
```val lastChild = getChildAt(0)
```

Comment: I don't know why but not scrolling to bottom for me!

Comment: This is the best answer. Doesn't look hacky and scrolls smoothly. If you need this behaviour in your on create method, be sure to wrap it in a postDelayed block or wait for the view layout to be fully layed out

Answer (score 58):

Sometimes scrollView.post doesn't work

```
 scrollView.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            scrollView.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_DOWN);
        }
    });
```

BUT if you use scrollView.postDelayed, it will definitely work

```
 scrollView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            scrollView.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_DOWN);
        }
    },1000);
```

Comment: thanks for the identification. postDelayed is better solution.

Comment: @Prashant :) :) :)

Comment: Just remember that you need to dispose of your Runnable when you finish the activity

Comment: how can one dispose of the runnable @FabioR

Answer (score 39):

What worked best for me is

```
scroll_view.post(new Runnable() {
     @Override
     public void run() {
         // This method works but animates the scrolling 
         // which looks weird on first load
         // scroll_view.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN);

         // This method works even better because there are no animations.
         scroll_view.scrollTo(0, scroll_view.getBottom());
     }
});
```

Comment: I tried this, but the algorithm here is wrong. Check my answer at the bottom please.

Answer (score 28):

I increment to work perfectly.

```
    private void sendScroll(){
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {Thread.sleep(100);} catch (InterruptedException e) {}
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        scrollView.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
                    }
                });
            }
        }).start();
    }
```

---

**Note**

This answer is a workaround for really old versions of android. Today the [`postDelayed`](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/view/View.html#postDelayed%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long%29) has no more that bug and you should use it.

Comment: Not above two, but this works well in my phone (LG JellyBean 4.1.2 Optimus G).

Comment: Why not use scrollView.postDelayed(runnable, 100)?

Comment: @MattWolfe at the time does not worked in some old versions of android. But today this answer is deprecated at all.

Comment: For the love of god, use scrollView.postDelayed(runnable, 100)! :)

Comment: I added a note @AlexLockwood I hope the people use the `postDelayed` :)

Answer (score 9):

i tried that successful.

```
scrollView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        scrollView.smoothScrollTo(0, scrollView.getHeight());
    }
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is some other ways to scroll to bottom

```
fun ScrollView.scrollToBottom() {
    // use this for scroll immediately
    scrollTo(0, this.getChildAt(0).height) 

    // or this for smooth scroll
    //smoothScrollBy(0, this.getChildAt(0).height)

    // or this for **very** smooth scroll
    //ObjectAnimator.ofInt(this, "scrollY", this.getChildAt(0).height).setDuration(2000).start()
}
```

**Using**

If you scrollview already laid out

```
my_scroll_view.scrollToBottom()
```

If your scrollview is not finish laid out (eg: you scroll to bottom in Activity `onCreate` method ...)

```
my_scroll_view.post { 
   my_scroll_view.scrollToBottom()          
}
```

Answer (score 3):

When the view is not loaded yet, you cannot scroll. You can do it 'later' with a post or sleep call as above, but this is not very elegant.

It is better to plan the scroll and do it on the next onLayout(). Example code here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10209457/1310343

Answer (score 3):

One thing to consider is what NOT to set.  Make certain your child controls, especially EditText controls, do not have the RequestFocus property set.  This may be one of the last interpreted properties on the layout and it will override gravity settings on its parents (the layout or ScrollView).

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly the answer to the question, but I needed to scroll down as soon as an EditText got the focus. However the accepted answer would make the ET also lose focus right away (to the ScrollView I assume).

My workaround was the following:

```
emailEt.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if(hasFocus){
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "got the focus", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            scrollView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    scrollView.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_DOWN);
                }
            }, 200);
        }else {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "lost the focus", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I actually found that calling fullScroll twice does the trick:

```
myScrollView.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN);

myScrollView.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        myScrollView.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
    }
});
```

It may have something to do with the activation of the post() method right after performing the first (unsuccessful) scroll. I think this behavior occurs after any previous method call on myScrollView, so you can try replacing the first fullScroll() method by anything else that may be relevant to you.

Answer (score 0):

Using there is another cool way to do this with Kotlin coroutines. The advantage of using a coroutine opposed to a Handler with a runnable (post/postDelayed) is that it does not fire up an expensive thread to execute a delayed action.

```
launch(UI){
    delay(300)
    scrollView.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN)
}
```

It is important to specify the coroutine's HandlerContext as UI otherwise the delayed action might not be called from the UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

In those case were using just **scroll.scrollTo(0, sc.getBottom())** don't work, use it using **scroll.post**

Example:

```
scroll.post(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
  scroll.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
  } 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible reason of why `scroll.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN)` might not work even wrapped in `.post()` is that the view is not laid out. In this case [View.doOnLayout()](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/core/view/package-summary#doonlayout) could be a better option:

```
scroll.doOnLayout(){
    scroll.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN)
}
```

Or, something more elaborated for the brave souls: https://chris.banes.dev/2019/12/03/suspending-views/

Answer (score 0):

If your minimum SDK is 29 or upper you could use this:

```
View childView = findViewById(R.id.your_view_id_in_the_scroll_view)
if(childView != null){
  scrollview.post(() -> scrollview.scrollToDescendant(childView));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A combination of all answers did the trick for me:

### Extension Function PostDelayed

```
private fun ScrollView.postDelayed(
    time: Long = 325, // ms
    block: ScrollView.() -> Unit
) {
    postDelayed({block()}, time)
}
```

### Extension Function measureScrollHeight

```
fun ScrollView.measureScrollHeight(): Int {
    val lastChild = getChildAt(childCount - 1)
    val bottom = lastChild.bottom + paddingBottom
    val delta = bottom - (scrollY+ height)
    return delta
}
```

### Extension Function ScrolltoBottom

```
fun ScrollView.scrollToBottom() {
    postDelayed {
        smoothScrollBy(0, measureScrollHeight())
    }
}
```

Be aware that the minimum delay should be at least 325ms or the scrolling will be buggy (not scrolling to the entire bottom). The larger your delta between the current height and the bottom is, the larger should be the delayed time.

Answer (score 0):

Some people here said that scrollView.post didn't work.

If you don't want to use scrollView.postDelayed, another option is to use a listener. Here is what I did in another use case :

```
ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener viewVisibilityChanged = new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onPreDraw() {
        if (my_view.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
            scroll_view.smoothScrollTo(0, scroll_view.getHeight());
        }
        return true;
    }
};
```

You can add it to your view this way :

```
my_view.getViewTreeObserver().addOnPreDrawListener(viewVisibilityChanged);
```

Answer (score -1):

This works **instantly**. Without delay.

```java
// wait for the scroll view to be laid out
scrollView.post(new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
    // then wait for the child of the scroll view (normally a LinearLayout) to be laid out
    scrollView.getChildAt(0).post(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        // finally scroll without animation
        scrollView.scrollTo(0, scrollView.getBottom());
      }
    }
  }
}
```