# How to move the control to the bottom of a TextView in ScrollView ( Scroll to bottom)

Tags: android, scroll, textview, scrollview

In my layout I have a `TextView` inside a `ScrollView`. But I am unable to scroll to the bottom of the `TextView` programmatically.

I have tried with `setSelection(int)` but the method is undefined for `TextView`. So can any one help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can try these posts

[First Link][1]

or

[Second Link][2]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6438061/can-i-scroll-a-scrollview-programmatically-in-android
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3080402/android-scrollview-force-to-bottom

Comment: Check this thread. You will find answer to your question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6438061/can-i-scroll-a-scrollview-programmatically-in-android

Comment: @ AnujMathur_07 and Nickolai Astashonok  : thank you guys for pointing me in to the correct direction.I have updated the question with the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok finally i got the work around.

```
TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);//my text view
ScrollView sv = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrollView);//my scrollview
String log ="a Very long text";
tv.setText(log);
sv.post(new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
    sv.scrollTo(0, tv.getHeight());
  }
});
```

Comment: we are srolling the view in **post** method because we need to wait untill the scrollview is completely loaded.before that we will be unable to scroll that.