# AdjustResize with a custom EditText not working correctly

Tags: android, android-layout, android-softkeyboard

I have an EditText using a background with a big height, when I click on my EditText, the screen shifts up to show the soft keyboard, but not the entire EditText stays visible. The bottom part of the Edit Text background disappears because the soft keyboard goes up in it.
I need that my screen shifts up a little more! How could I do that?

Tks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think its better to use a **ScrollView**.
Using this will shift the entire screen up.
Try it out once

Comment: I'm already using a ScrollView. But it didn't shifts up till the end. If I swipe up my finger on it, I can see the small peace that dissapeared. What could I do to scrollview shifts 100% up?

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3080402/android-scrollview-force-to-bottom link

Answer (score 0):

Create a empty layout and put it at the bottom of the screen by property align parent bottom set to true.

Now set your edittext above it. Add property layout_above and pass the id of the layout.

Now in the manifest, add screensize to config changes attribute for that activity or in the application tag