# Android scroll to bottom when keyboard appears

Tags: android, authentication, screen

I think i tried all the solutions on internet but at my login screen login button is still under the keyboard. 
I want to scroll to the bottom automatically when keyboard appears. 
Here is my xml codes

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true"
android:scrollbars="none" >


<RelativeLayout 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:background="#13a7d8"
 >

  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="-120dp"
    android:src="@drawable/logo_login" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="220dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_width="220dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/benimlabel2"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPassword" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_marginTop="-130dp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText1"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:text="@string/eposta"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/benimlabel2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText2"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:text="@string/sifre"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />



<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="220dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="@string/girisyap" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:text="Hesabın yoksa, hemen kayıt ol"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:onClick="kayitol" />

</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

and I tried different solutions at manifest file

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustPan"
```

other try

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible"
```

how can i fix this?

Comment: Did you try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3080402/android-scrollview-force-to-bottom ?

Comment: put login button at a side rather below OR let it hide Login button and perform Login operation on "Done" press in IME(Soft KeyBoard)

Comment: yes i tried but didnot work. Because my xml is not scrollable. When keyboard appears i cant scroll screen.

Comment: thanks Arnav M, but my target users will look for a login button. And login button at side will narrow other objects.

Comment: Try to use : android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize"

Comment: Thanks Haresh. Didnot work. I think i have a problem at xml.

Comment: you also remove android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" this code from your xml theme always define under <application tag in AndroidManifest.xml.

Comment: I think you have to put button out side scroll view shall i provide demo code for this ?

Comment: Haresh a demo will be wonderful

Answer (score 0):

This code worked for me.

Put this in onResume() of your activity

```
((ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.ScrollView01)).post(new Runnable() 
{
    public void run() 
    {
        ((ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.ScrollView01)).fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
}
});
```

Comment: I saw this code before but i dont know where to put this code

Comment: I tried like this     
@Override
    protected void onResume() {
     ((ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.ScrollView01)).post(new Runnable() 
     {
         public void run() 
         {
             ((ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.ScrollView01)).fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
     }
     });
    }

but code error :(

Comment: ((ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.ScrollView01))
no suggestions avilable