# How Scroll android Scrollview automatically and lock it when comes to bottom

Tags: android, locking, scrollview

I am creating app that needs to scroll slowlly the scrollview automatically to bottom and lock at the bottom. I have tried several ways but it does not functuation correctly? any library or source code?

Answer (score 2):

[Android: ScrollView force to bottom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3080402/android-scrollview-force-to-bottom/3080483#3080483)

Check this link. May be you get the desired result.

**Edit:**

```
new CountDownTimer(2000, 20) {          
 public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {             
   scrolView.scrollTo((x,y));         
 }          
 public void onFinish() {  
 }      
}.start();
```

or instead of scrollTo() try using scrollBy()

Comment: I need to do scrolling slowly