# scrolling up a scroll view onclick of a button

Tags: android, scrollview, android-animation, scrolltop, scrollto

I have a view and a textview in a linearlayout. That LinearLayout is present in a ScrollView. I want that scrollView to move down onclicking a button in that screen and again move up onclicking that again

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3080402/android-scrollview-force-to-bottom

Comment: how to slow it so that we can view that?

Comment: I am unable to figure out whether its scrolling or not

Comment: what about using scrollTo(x, y) method . With each click you can move view to some specific pixels.

Comment: i mentioned it as scrollTo(0,0). Then it has to go up but its not

Answer (score 1):

To scroll down on button click you should use this:

```
scrollView.post(new Runnable()
            {
                @Override
                public void run()
                {
                    //X,Y are scroll positions untill where you want scroll down
                    scrollView.scrollTo(X, Y);
                }
            });
```

To scroll up on button click you should use this:

```
scrollView.post(new Runnable()
            {
                @Override
                public void run()
                {
                    //X,Y are scroll positions untill where you want scroll up
                    int X=0,Y=0;
                    scrollView.scrollTo(X, Y);
                }
            });
```

Comment: Its not working. I have a ImageButton at the parentbottom and ScrollView in a LinearLayout below that. I want to move the layout in scrollview up on click of Image Button

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

```
private ImageView list_scroll_iv;
private int focus_pos=1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    list_scroll_iv = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.list_scroll_iv);
    list_scroll_iv.setOnClickListener(this);
}



@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    list_sv.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //1 for up and 2 for down
          if(focus_pos==1) {
              list_sv.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_DOWN);
              focus_pos=2;
              list_scroll_iv.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.blue_arrow_ic_up));
          }
          else {
              list_sv.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_UP);
              focus_pos=1;
              list_scroll_iv.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.blue_arrow_ic_down));
          }
        }
    });

}
```