# Auto scroll in Scrollview

Tags: android, scrollview, autoscroll

How to auto scroll bottom-to-top at a particular position in ScrollView to make it look like as Drag-to-scroll-up in ScrollView?

Basically, I want to create a wheel that spins from bottom to top with smoothly.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#smoothScrollToPositionFromTop%28int,%20int%29

Answer (score 2):

You can make scrollview to scroll and add some sleep for smooth scrolling :

```
private void sendScroll(ScrollView scrollView){
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {Thread.sleep(100);} catch (InterruptedException e) {}
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        scrollView.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_UP);
                    }
                });
            }
        }).start();
    }
```

Comment: This works, but this approach is simpler using scroll.post instead. https://stackoverflow.com/a/4524131/5163090

Answer (score -1):

Add the below lines :

```
scroll.scrollTo(0, scroll.getBottom());
```

in your XML add:

```
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```