# Gravity bottom, text doesn't scroll up

Tags: java, android

[image]

Sorry if I somehow missed the answer to my question, I was trying to find it. So, the problem is when I put my textView into ScrollView I faced a little problem. In the beginning I had always had to scroll my text down myself. Then I added

```
<TextView
  ...
  android:layout_gravity="bottom"
>
```

And faced another problem. Now my text appears in bottom, just like what I needed, but I can't scroll my text up to see what text I missed, for instance, it just doesn't scroll now. At all.

```
<TextView
    ...
    android:layout_gravity="top"
>
```

With this setting Text appears in top, no autoscrolldown, but at least I can scrolldown myself. Why with layout_gravity="bottom" I can't scroll?

Comment: please use Edit text instead of Text view and set editable false property of that and remove scroll view no need for scroll view.

Comment: Please provide the screenshots

Comment: If I don't use layout_gravity="bottom" text doesn't scrolldown itself (which is obvious), but I can scroll it down myself. But when I added gravity text scrolls down itself, but I can't scroll it up... I'll try to use Edit Text later, but I didn't notice setEditable method there.. Quite new to android, sorry

Answer (score 2):

Add text view after close of scrollview and add property for text view which you want like:                                                                                                                ......   ......

Comment: It worked, thanks, just needed to change layout_gravity to just gravity. Thank you very much. Only one thing is making me sad now: scrolling is not that smooth anymore

Answer (score 0):

I think u should look at the problem in a different perspective. Look at this

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3080483/5852891

Contents should not over flow from screen view port. That is the rectangle part of the screen that is renders display.

[image: Design Preview of designing apps in android]

See the contents must fit in the screen. This can be set with layout weights and positioning codes.

Comment: But with layout_gravity="top" scrolling in both sides works, that's why I can't understand where is the problem. I don't think that I did understand your answer fully. And I saw this answer you hyperlinked before, but I was just wondering if I could get along without it. Thank you.

Comment: We didn't understand each other, unfortunately:(

Answer (score 0):

You can implement the scroll view behaviour of TextView without using a ScrollView.

Set these in the xml for TextView

```
android:maxLines = "SOME_INTEGER"
android:scrollbars = "vertical"
```

And then use this in Java code:

```
yourTextView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
```

Comment: Oh, it actually works now, just needed to change layout_gravity to just gravity. Thank you very much. Only one thing is making me sad now: scrolling is not that smooth

Comment: @JaWrecker Okay Nice. If scrolling is not smooth with ScrollView, you can try to use my way. For me, scrolling is quite good.

Comment: Scrolling was smooth with ScrollView, but now I made changes and deleted ScrollView, then scrolling became not that smooth, I meant that :(